# Google Apps Marketplace V1 domain authorization broken

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

As of last night, our app is no longer authorized to access Google API's for new domains that install it.

From our end, we are receiving the [licensing notifications](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/marketplace/licensing?hl=zh-TW&csw=1) when a domain installs our app, and we can also retrieve notifications from the FeedServerClient to get the installing admin's email address, but that's the only thing that is still working.

No UserProvisioning API's nor GoogleApps data-level API's can be run without a 401 error.

We did make a change to the "Full Overview" text field in our GAMv1 entry last night, but we did not change the other parts of the manifest in any way, nor did we change any scopes.

Domains that installed yesterday (or before "2014-06-09 23:00:00 GMT" to put a closer timeline on it) are working fine.

Comment: Are you still experiencing the issue?